# kernel panic Hardware Error - what hardware is responsible?

Tags: ubuntu, kernel-panic

I'm having kernel panics every other day.  below is a transcript of a photo of the console.
How do I determine what hardware is responsible for the problem? (or is it software)

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server

```
[Hardware Error]: CPU:2   MC0_STATUS[-|UE|-|-|AddrV|UECC]: 0xb400200055000145
[Hardware Error]: MC0_ADDR: 0x0000000164fe77b0
[Hardware Error]: Data Cache Error: Data/Tag DWR error.
[Hardware Error]: cache level: L1, tx: DATA, mem-tx: DWR
[Hardware Error]: CPU:3 MC0_STATUS[-|UE|-|PCC|AddrV|CECC]: 0xb66b400000000135
[Hardware Error]: MC0_ADDR: 0x0000000164fe77b0
[Hardware Error]: Data Cache Error: Data/Tag DWD error.
[Hardware Error]: cache level: L1, tx: DATA, mem-tx: DRD
[Hardware Error]: CPU 3: Machine Check Exception: 4 Bank 0: b66b400000000135
[Hardware Error]: TSC bc02bd350de4 ADDR 164fe7bb0
[Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 2:100f42 TIME 1378965147 SOCKET 0 APIC 3 microcode 10000c6
[Hardware Error]: CPU:3 MC0_STATUS[-|UE|-|PCC|AddrV|CECC]: 0xb66b400000000135
[Hardware Error]: MC0_ADDR: 0x0000000164fe77b0
[Hardware Error]: Data Cache Error: Data/Tag DWD error.
[Hardware Error]: cache level: L1, tx: DATA, mem-tx: DRD
[Hardware Error]: Machine Check: Invalid
Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal machine check on current CPU
Shutting down cpus with NMI
```

Here is some additional logging that I found:

```
kernel: [58495.948100] ------------[ cut here ]------------
kernel: [58495.948108] WARNING: at /build/buildd/linux-lts-quantal-3.5.0/net/sched/sch_generic.c:255 dev_watchdog+0x272/0x280()
kernel: [58495.948109] Hardware name: MS-7576
kernel: [58495.948110] NETDEV WATCHDOG: eth0 (r8169): transmit queue 0 timed out
kernel: [58495.948111] Modules linked in: nfsd nfs lockd fscache auth_rpcgss nfs_acl sunrpc xfs vesafb radeon ttm drm_kms_helper snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_intel drm snd_hda_codec wmi i2c_algo_bit snd_hwdep snd_pcm snd_timer snd soundcore snd_page_alloc lp shpchp r8169 sp5100_tco i2c_piix4 firewire_ohci parport firewire_core kvm_amd edac_core k10temp edac_mce_amd serio_raw kvm mac_hid microcode crc_itu_t raid10 raid456 async_pq async_xor xor async_memcpy async_raid6_recov raid6_pq async_tx raid1 raid0 multipath linear pata_atiixp
kernel: [58495.948136] Pid: 0, comm: swapper/3 Tainted: G   M         3.5.0-23-generic #35~precise1-Ubuntu
kernel: [58495.948137] Call Trace:
kernel: [58495.948138]  <IRQ>  [<ffffffff81052c9f>] warn_slowpath_common+0x7f/0xc0
kernel: [58495.948144]  [<ffffffff81052d96>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x46/0x50
kernel: [58495.948146]  [<ffffffff815a05b2>] dev_watchdog+0x272/0x280
kernel: [58495.948149]  [<ffffffff8101be03>] ? native_sched_clock+0x13/0x80
kernel: [58495.948151]  [<ffffffff810702d0>] ? __queue_work+0x330/0x330
kernel: [58495.948153]  [<ffffffff815a0340>] ? pfifo_fast_dequeue+0xe0/0xe0
kernel: [58495.948154]  [<ffffffff815a0340>] ? pfifo_fast_dequeue+0xe0/0xe0
kernel: [58495.948156]  [<ffffffff81062ce6>] call_timer_fn+0x46/0x160
kernel: [58495.948158]  [<ffffffff815a0340>] ? pfifo_fast_dequeue+0xe0/0xe0
kernel: [58495.948159]  [<ffffffff81064632>] run_timer_softirq+0x132/0x2a0
kernel: [58495.948162]  [<ffffffff810a4105>] ? ktime_get+0x65/0xe0
kernel: [58495.948164]  [<ffffffff8105ba88>] __do_softirq+0xa8/0x210
kernel: [58495.948166]  [<ffffffff810ab264>] ? tick_program_event+0x24/0x30
kernel: [58495.948168]  [<ffffffff816a841c>] call_softirq+0x1c/0x30
kernel: [58495.948170]  [<ffffffff81016245>] do_softirq+0x65/0xa0
kernel: [58495.948172]  [<ffffffff8105be6e>] irq_exit+0x8e/0xb0
kernel: [58495.948174]  [<ffffffff816a8d5e>] smp_apic_timer_interrupt+0x6e/0x99
kernel: [58495.948176]  [<ffffffff816a7aca>] apic_timer_interrupt+0x6a/0x70
kernel: [58495.948177]  <EOI>  [<ffffffff8103ff56>] ? native_safe_halt+0x6/0x10
kernel: [58495.948180]  [<ffffffff8101c993>] default_idle+0x53/0x1f0
kernel: [58495.948182]  [<ffffffff8101d8a9>] cpu_idle+0xd9/0x120
kernel: [58495.948184]  [<ffffffff8167b237>] start_secondary+0xc3/0xc5
kernel: [58495.948185] ---[ end trace ef52dc6dad6ceea1 ]---    

# dmidecode -t 1 -t 3 -t 4 | egrep '(Manufacturer|Product|Serial|Socket|Version)'
Manufacturer: MICRO-STAR INTERNATIONAL CO.,LTD
Product Name: MS-7576
Version: 1.0
Serial Number: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
Manufacturer: MICRO-STAR INTERNATIONAL CO.,LTD
Version: 1.0
Serial Number: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
Socket Designation: CPU1
Manufacturer: AMD
Version: AMD Phenom(tm) II X4 B50 Processor
Serial Number: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
```

Comment: I would check the RAM first, with `memtest86`, which is part of about every Linux installation CD and maybe even in your boot menu.

Comment: Looks like a cache error in the CPU.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, this is a hardware problem, mostly because of the ring-buffer output that says, `[Hardware Error]`.

I'd suspect system board, CPU socket or CPU...

Do you have any details about the hardware? What does the following string report?

```
dmidecode -t 1 -t 3 -t 4 | egrep '(Manufacturer|Product|Serial|Socket|Version)'
```

Comment: dmidecode output added above

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're having RAM errors. You can verify this by running memtest86.

Also, if you have the mcelog package installed, check /var/log/mcelog for more information.

I'd recommend moving to a server-class motherboard that can handle ECC RAM.

Comment: I ran memtest86+, it returned no errors.  Now what?

Answer (score 1):

I see a **Machine Check Exception**. That means that the CPU has detected a problems.

MCE can be as easy as reading data from cache, seeing an ECC error and trying again. These kinds of errors do happen now and then. (Which is why CPU do try again for a limited number of times).

In your case we also see:

```
Data Cache Error: Data/Tag DWR error.
cache level: L1, tx: DATA, mem-tx: DWR
```

That is an error with the first level cache (which is next to a CPU core and on the same die). It is not an error with main memory.

The rest of you transscript shows multiple errors, some of the same type but not always with the same core.  At this point I would start to worry that the CPU is failing. First thing to check is if the CPU is not overheating.

> How do I determine what hardware is responsible for the problem? (or is it software)

MCE errors are often hardware. Which seems to match the errors you got.

If you have a spare CPU, try that one.

If not, make sure the system is properly cooled and monitor the temperature over time.

If you have not already done so, install [mcelog](http://www.mcelog.org/) and ready up on [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine-check_exception).

Answer (score 0):

I have just encountered this error on a Dell XPS 420 Core2 Quad Q6600

This machine had some breathing problems in the past from previous owners and was extremely dirty inside (smokers) and would heat up to the point of rebooting randomly. I am not sure how long this went on.

I went into the BIOS and disabled 2 cores on the CPU and all seems to be working fine now - seems that the CPU had overheated enough to actually burn out 2 (or 1 as I can only disable 2 at a time) cores.

Machine works fine now as a dual core.